# Facebook Error Invalid API Key

Tags: android, facebook, api-key

I am trying to post an image to facebook wall from my android application. I am using the facebook sdk.

From my `MainActivity` when i call `FBConnectionActivity` to get the connection and ID, I get a null pointer exception

I am calling 2 methods like this:-

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
          setConnection();
          getID();
     }
}
```

In the `FBConnectionActivity`, these two methods are defined as:

```
    public void setConnection() {
            mContext = this;
            mFacebook = Utility.mFacebook;
            mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    }    
    public void getID(TextView txtUserName, ProgressBar progbar) {
            username = txtUserName;
            pb = progbar;
            if (isSession()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
                    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
            } else {
                    // no logged in, so relogin
                    Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
                    mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
            }
    }    
    public void getID(){

        if (isSession()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
                mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
        } else {
                // no logged in, so relogin
                Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
                mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
        }
    }
```

In the call to `isSession()`, the method call to `isSessionValid()` method always returns false.

```
 public boolean isSession() {
            sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
            Long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
            Log.d(TAG, access_token);

            if (access_token != null && expires != -1) {
                Log.e("isSession() method ", "acess_token : " + access_token );
                    mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                    mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }
            return mFacebook.isSessionValid();
    }

 public boolean isSessionValid() {
        return (getAccessToken() != null) &&
                ((getAccessExpires() == 0) ||
                        (System.currentTimeMillis() < getAccessExpires()));
 }
```

If my session is not valid , how do i obtain a new valid access token. Every time i try to upload an image from  my application, the method `isSessionValid()` returns false. Also i am getting the following error:-

```
01-18 12:46:35.928: D/Facebook-Example(28459): Response: {"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid API key","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"photos.upload"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
01-18 12:46:35.948: W/Facebook-Example(28459): Facebook Error: Invalid API key
```

Please help me.

I am using the following method for posting the image on facebook. Is there anything wrong here?

```
public void postImageonWall() {
        Log.e("BrowsePictureActivity ", "Inside postImageonWall method");
        byte[] data = null;

        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();

        Log.d("BrowsePictureActivity ", "data.length : " + data.length);

        Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(),
            null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted your code snippet that includes Posting image to Facebook wall

```
If you map wrong Key and Value Pair you will get Invalid API Key.
```

So ensure that you are using correct Key and Value Pair for Post image and be careful while you add attachments along with images.

Try this for Posting Image to Facebook wall :

```
private void postToWall(String accessToken) {   
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new   AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); // bm is bitmap object of your image
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param = new Bundle();
    param.putString("message", "All");
    param.putString("filename", "Test");
    param.putByteArray("image", byteArray);
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new fbRequestListener(), null);

}

public class fbRequestListener implements RequestListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,Object state) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the following method for posting the image on facebook. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: I m sorry i am new to android and stackoverflow. I didn't understand what you mean when u said 'If you map wrong Key and Value Pair you will get Invalid API Key.'. Thanks again for help.